# Unique node pointing to other node, but with same value in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use an OpenStreetMap dataset in Neo4j, that I want to restructure.
I know how I can make unique `Street` and `Zip` labelled nodes, by using `MERGE()`.

```
MERGE(street:Street {street_name: n.`addr:street`})
MERGE(zip:ZipCode {zipcode: n.`addr:postcode`})
```

But I also want `Housenumber` labelled nodes, numbers can sometimes be the same,
but those numbers never point to the same street.
I think `MERGE()` isn't fully suitable for this.

So, I want the **structure** to be something like this:

```
Street<-number_in_street<-Housenumber
ZipCode<-number_in_zipcode<-Housenumber

Coolstreet<-number_in_street<-20A (Unique Housenumber node 1)
Otherstreet<-number_in_street<-20A (Unique Housenumber node 2)
5680 PC<-number_in_zipcode<-20A (Unique Housenumber node 1)
5680 PC<-number_in_zipcode<-20A (Unique Housenumber node 2)
```

How can I achieve this structure, with Cypher, by using an OpenStreetMap dataset in Neo4j?

**Edit:**
I don't want to *duplicate* the street names, to have a certain combination with a house number.
I want street and housenumber as a seperate node (*to prevent duplication*).
One unique street needs to point to several housenumbers, that are in that street.

So I have blank labbeled nodes like this:

```
addr:housenumber:199A
addr:street:Coolstreet
source:BAG
addr:postcode:5414 AP
```

That needs to be splitted to Street, Housenumber and Zipcode,
whill having the requested structure.

Comment: Do you want a new `Housenumber` node for *every* address? Or a set of unique numbers for both streets and zipcodes? And why? Would help to describe your case a bit more.

Comment: @MartinPreusse To prevent duplication, see my edit for a example of a blank node, that needs to be "splitted" with having the requested structure.

Comment: I don't get it. What defines the 'uniqueness' of the housenumber nodes you are talking about? Why not just `MERGE` housenumber nodes like you `MERGE` the others and create relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MERGE` will prevent duplication exactly the way you want. If you want to get the housenumber and street together on a node so that you can apply a uniqueness constraint, you're misusing the uniqueness constraint; it's really for optimizing index lookups, deduplicating is just a side effect.

Something like this should work:

```
WITH n
MERGE (z:ZipCode {zipcode: n.`addr:postcode`})
MERGE (s:Street {street_name: n.`addr:street`})
MERGE (s) - [:NUMBER_IN_STREET] -> (n:HouseNumber {house_number: n.`addr:housenumber`})
MERGE (z) - [:NUMBER_IN_ZIPCODE] -> (n)
```

`MERGE`ing the `HouseNumber` as part of the whole pattern ensures that it is unique for that street name. You can even put a regular index (non-unique) on the `house_number` property to speed things up a bit.